# how to fix, Curly brackets causing unexpected behavior while parsing HTML using Simple HTML DOM

Tags: php, html, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

i am trying to parse HTML file using `PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser`

i have found issue while parsing page having unclosed `curly brackets`. i.e. `{`

here is sample `HTML`

```
<html>
<body>
<span>a</span>
<span>{b</span>
<span>c}</span>
<span>d</span>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP code

```
<?php
    $html = file_get_html('test.html');
    foreach ($html->find('span') as $v) {
    echo $v->innertext."\n";
}
```

**expected:**

```
A
{b
c}
d
```

**result is follwings:**

```
a
{b</span>  <span>c}
d
```

How can i fix it ?

looks like this is known bug and actually submitted on 2013-10-27 https://sourceforge.net/p/simplehtmldom/bugs/136/

is simple-html-dom project dead ?

Comment: if there's no solution yet, why not use `DOMDocument`? plus its built-in

Comment: i couldnt find much documentation on it, simple html dom is really simple in terms of documenetation too., thanks

Comment: no documentation? php already [has](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and a lot here on SO, no shortage in fact. anyway, most likely the library parser's fault, you could try to fix it yourself, its a single php file anyway